# How to recup var in google.script.run

Tags: javascript, function

I have a question with this code:

```html
<td><input type="button" value="Valider" name="submit" id="submitButton" onclick="foo()"/></td></div>
```

```js
function foo(){
       vrailastRow = 0;
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(lastRow){  
           vrailastRow=lastRow-1;
           console.log(vrailastRow); // => Display value 8
       }).withFailureHandler(function(error){
           console.log('error');
       }).lastR();

       console.log(vrailastRow); // => Display value 0 (value define at start)
}
```

First `console.log` prints value 8 but second `console.log` prints 0.
I don't arrive to use vrailastRow out of `google.script.run`

Any idea?

Function .gs :

```js
    function lastR() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    return lastRow;
    }
```

Comment: Where do you define the variable vrialastRow and which value does it have?

Comment: I define it just before Google.script.run. The value inside Google.script.run is 8 but thé value in the console at the end of program return 0. Value définie at the start